# Disabling Menu Recovery Mode for user groups

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, menu

I'm actually trying to get two administration level for my Joomla Website.

- The first is the standard Super User with the standard admin menu
- The second is a "Communication Admin" with only some items in its admin menu.

That's exactly what I want but, when I'm logging with the "Communication" account, I've a notification on all page saying

> **Warning**
>
> The administrator menu Communication does not have - Menu Manager, Module
>   Manager. Select to turn on the menu recovery mode.

Is there a possibility to disable this annoying popup for a user groups or for everyone as well

Comment: In this Joomlashack tutorial about setting up custom admin menus, in Step #4 it shows a screen print of the Advanced Tab with a 'Check menu' option that I understand will disable the check that is producing your message. How it fits in to what you have implemented there is not enough detail in your question to know, but I hope it helps. https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/new-admin-menus/

Comment: Yes, that just fixed my problem ! Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Irata, I found a option in :

- Menus (Column Linked Module) > Your module Name > Check Menu

And set this option to "No"

Hope this help someone else

[image: Check Menu Optio]

Source : https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/new-admin-menus/